# Similar problem to Taylor's theorem proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

[image: Chanbody]

> **43.** Let $a_1,\dots,a_{n+1}$ be arbitrary points in $[a,b]$ and let
>   $$Q(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(x-x_i).$$
>   Suppose that $f$ is $(n+1)$-times differentiable and that $P$ is a polynomial function of degree $\le n$ such that $P(x_i)=f(x_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n+1$. Show that for each $x$ in $[a,b]$  there is a number $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that
>   $$f(x)-P(x)= Q(x) \cdot \frac{f(n+1)(c)}{(n+1)!}.$$
>   Hint: consider the function
>   $$F(t)=Q(x)[f(t)-P(t)]-Q(t)[f(x)-P(x)].$$
>   Show that $F$ is zero at $n+2$ different points in $[a,b]$, and use Problem 42.

Problem 42 was:

> "Suppose that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable and that $f(x) = 0$ for $n+1$ different $x$. Prove that $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for some $x$. "

### I will start:

$$F(t) = Q(x)[f(t) - P(t)] - Q(t)[f(x) - P(x)]$$

$$F(a) = Q(x)[f(a) - P(a)] - Q(a)[f(x) - P(x)]$$

$$Q(a)  = \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} x- x_k = \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} a- a_k = (a- a_1)(a - a_2).... (a - a_{n+1})$$

But I don't see any options? Can someone guide me? Thanks!

### **PLEASE DO NOT GIVE A FULL ANSWER**

Comment: Hint: Think about Rolle.

Comment: Some hints: 1. What's the $(n+1)$-st derivative of $Q$? 2. What's the $(n+1)$-st derivative of $F$ (remember that $x$ is kept constant in $F(t)$)? 3. What is $F(x_i)$? 4. Can you find one more point where $F(t) = 0$? 5. How can you use problem 42 now?

Comment: Pictures cannot be searched for. While your question may have merit, and it's good that you show your work, and want to learn instead of having a full solution handed to you, it is not going to be of lasting value in its current form. Please [edit] it to use MathJax throughout.

Comment: It seems that this problem is taken from some book. Perhaps you could add information about the book. Where is this problem from?

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

1. Check that $F(t)=0$ for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1},x$.
2. Use [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) $n+1$-times.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(n+1)(n+2)/2$ times? But part 2 is already done for OP in "problem 42."

Comment: Yes, it depends on how you count: first for get that $f'(\xi_{i}^{1})=0$ for $n+1$ different $\xi_{i}^{1}$, second to get $f''(\xi_{i}^{2})=0$ for $n$ different $\xi_{i}^{2}$...

Comment: @agha, what if, let $a = a_1$ and let $b= a_{n+1}$. Then of course $f(a_1) - P(a_1) = 0$ but also, $Q(a_1) =  \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (a_1 - a_1_k)$ but I am not sure if the SECOND part of $F(t)$ comes out to be $0$?

Comment: It's because $Q(a_i)=0$. Note that if you put $a=a_1$ to $Q(a)=\Pi_{k=1}^{n+1}(a-a_k)$, then You have $\Pi_{k=1}^{n+1}(a_1-a_k)$ and $(a_1-a_1)=0$ appears in this product.

Answer (score 1):

This is a jigsaw puzzle, and there are only finitely many ways to fit the pieces together.  You are given the statement:

> **Problem 42** Suppose that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable and that $f(x)=0$ for $n+1$ different values of $x$.  Then $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for some $x$.

Let's rewrite that slightly:

> Suppose that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable and
>   $$
> f(x_1) = f(x_2) = \cdots = f(x_n) = f(x_{n+1}) = 0
> $$
>   for $n+1$ distinct points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1}$.  Then there exists a point $c$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(c) = 0$.

You are given a function $F(t) = Q(x) [f(t)-P(t)] - Q(t) [f(x) - P(x)]$ and directed to show that there are $n+2$ distinct values of $t$ for which $f(t) = 0$.  Then by Problem 42 there will be a point $c$ such that $F^{(n+1)}(c) = 0$.  If you are lucky $F^{(n+1)}(c)=0$ will imply that 
$$
f(x) - P(x) = Q(x) \cdot\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}
$$

The only question is which $n+2$ values of $t$ will yield $F(t) = 0$?  There are $n+1$ points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n+1}$ given.  Do they satisfy this equation?  Remember that you know something about $Q(x_i)$ and $P(x_i)$.  Can you find one more value of $t$?